# How to save a plot that doesn't save with common methods

Tags: r, plot, graph

This might be a more general version of this question ([How to save ggrough chart as .png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817353/how-to-save-ggrough-chart-as-png)).

I am using RStudio. I can typically save my plots usual ways (`png()`, `jpeg()`, and `ggsave()`.

However, I have encountered situations where the plot renders in the RStudio Viewer, but these aforementioned saving commands do not work.

Here is an example taken from the `remiotic` page at https://timelyportfolio.github.io/remiotic/:

```
library(remiotic)
remiotic(
    # lines expected to be an array of arrays
    #  for now do it the really ugly way
    #  but should be able to fix this fairly easily
    data = list(
        list(
            group = "A",
            coordinates = lapply(0:10, function(x) list(x=x, y=runif(1)))
        )
    ),
    frame = "XYFrame",
    props = list(
        shape = "lines",
        xAccessor = "x",
        yAccessor = "y",
        xExtent = c(0, 10),
        yExtent = c(0, 1),
        lineStyle = list(stroke = "#629"),
        margin = list(
            top = 20,
            right = 40,
            bottom = 50,
            left = 50
        ),
        axes = list(
            list(orient = "left"),
            list(orient = "bottom")
        )
    ),
    width = "100%"
)
```

I have tried putting `jpeg("file")`, `png("file")`, and `pdf("file")` before this code and `dev.off()` after. The first two do not create a file and the third does, but I can't open the file as it didn't save the plot to it. I have a Mac; if I put `x11()` in front, it opens the new window, but renders the plot in the RStudio Viewer.

How can I save a plot like this using code (and not RStudio's export button)?

Comment: Can you open it in browser and save it?

Comment: How would I do that from RStudio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rg <- remiotic(...)
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(rg, "remplot.html")
```

Or Webshot package would allow for capture as png.

```
library(webshot)
webshot("remplot.html", "remplot.png")
```

Comment: Pure gold. Really appreciate it!