# Add gradients and hand-drawn effects to gganimate plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, textures, gradient, gganimate

I am interested in using `gganimate` with gradients and hand-drawn and painty-type fill effects (see sketchy and painty and gradients here: https://semiotic.nteract.io/guides/sketchy-painty-patterns). Is this possible? I have found that `ggrough` (https://xvrdm.github.io/ggrough/) is able to convert `ggplot2` objects to have these kinds of effects. However, is it possible to use `ggrough` or some other thing to combine with `gganimate`?

And is there another way to do this, even in base `ggplot2` (i.e., not using `gganimate`?) Note that I fear the answer to both questions are no, particularly with gradient fills (see @hadley Hadley Wickhams's answer to this question: [How to add texture to fill colors in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2)).

Or is there another solution that still uses `ggplot2`, but not `gganimate`? I suppose that if it were possible in base `ggplot2` that I could make many individual files and stitch them together to make a .gif. Although in theory I could do this using the output from `ggrough`.

Comment: This might be possible as a sort of rube goldberg solution, but I don't see how to do it elegantly. You could take your data, use `tweenr` to interpolate across frames, then write a function to render each frame and save the output using something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817353/how-to-save-ggrough-chart-as-png   Then you could use `gifski` to combine the frames into a gif.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the suggestion and for letting me know about `tweenr`. I think this could work.

Comment: It might be possible to get around some of the restrictions of ggplot if you're willing to move to python- plotnine (ggplot clone) has both animation support (https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.animation.PlotnineAnimation.html) and support for custom themes. The closest pre-built one I can find would be xkcd- https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/plotnine/themes/theme_xkcd.html#theme_xkcd (wiggly lines, etc. like the comic). You should be able to add any parameters you could in matplotlib to plotnine.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on python - plotnine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option might be to use the `xkcd` library to get squiggly lines. It doesn't do squiggly fills, but it's a start and is in the right aesthetic neighborhood. I couldn't get it to work out of the box with `gganimate`, but it's possible to prep your data with `tweenr` (the same package `gganimate` relies on) and feed that into `gganimate::transition_manual` to decent effect:

### [image]

Here's how. Given this fake data:

```
library(tidyverse); library(gganimate)
df <- tibble(Group = rep(1:3, times = 3),
             value = c(1:6, 3:1),
             period = rep(1:3, each = 3))
```

We could animate with `geom_rect` and `gganimate::transition_states`. `geom_col` would be easier here, but I want to show similarity to `xkcd::xkcdrect` later.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = df,
           aes(xmin = Group - 0.4, xmax = Group + 0.4,
               ymin = 0, ymax = value), 
           fill = "gray80") +
  transition_states(period)
```

[image]

I get an error when I drop in the `xkcd::xkcdrect` equivalent:

```
# Doesn't work
ggplot() +
  xkcd::xkcdrect(aes(xmin = Group - 0.4, xmax = Group + 0.4,
                     ymin = 0, ymax = value), fill = "gray80",
                 df) +
  transition_states(period)
```

> Error in if (nrow(from) == 0 && nrow(to) == 0) { :    missing value
>   where TRUE/FALSE needed In addition: Warning messages: 1: In
>   rep("raw", length = nrow(from)) :   first element used of 'length.out'
>   argument 2: In rep("raw", length = nrow(to)) :   first element used of
>   'length.out' argument 3: In rep(NA_integer_, length = nrow(to)) :
>   first element used of 'length.out' argument

But we can get to the same place by prepping the tweened data manually, and then feed that into `transition_manual`:

```
df_tween <- tweenr::tween_states(
  list(df[1:3,],
       df[4:6,],
       df[7:9,],
       df[1:3,]), 3, 1, 'cubic-in-out', 100)


  ggplot() +
  xkcd::xkcdrect(aes(xmin = Group - 0.4, xmax = Group + 0.4,
                     ymin = 0, ymax = value), fill = "gray80",
                 df_tween) +
  transition_manual(.frame)
```